# Can't find the sql data on Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm sure that i have created a sql table , here is my logcat

```
06-15 12:26:09.185 3631-3631/? D/Name:: Id: 1 ,Name: Andy ,Phone: 91000
06-15 12:26:09.185 3631-3631/? D/Name:: Id: 2 ,Name: Tom ,Phone: 92000
06-15 12:26:09.185 3631-3631/? D/Name:: Id: 3 ,Name: John ,Phone: 93000
06-15 12:26:09.185 3631-3631/? D/Name:: Id: 4 ,Name: Mary ,Phone: 94000
```

I think that it should be android device monitor , then go to data>data>[my app package name]>databases .

But i can't find the data>data .

I use mac .  Some one can tell me what step may i miss it . Thanks in advance.
[image]

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting...");
        db.addContact(new Contact("Andy", "91000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Tom", "92000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("John", "93000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Mary", "94000"));

        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contact...");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: " +cn.getID()+ " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
//Adding new contact
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    //Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    //Closing database connection
    db.close();
}

//Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    System.out.println("table is here");
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: data>data will not be accessible in real device. Either create database in external storage or use emulator

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply , i use emulator just like the android device monitor photo .

Comment: try creating in external storage too but later move it back to default location

Comment: Search for `adb pull` database command for mac and view your database.

Comment: @Henry I want to check the sql database file that i have created it on my emulator.

Comment: Which API version is there in emulator?

Comment: Android 7.0 API 24

Comment: I think it's a bug and you can see this link:- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37123176

Comment: I try to lower my api of emulator right now.

Comment: And also notice Android Studio version from 2.3 to 2.4..https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37123176#comment25

Comment: Is that working on lower api?

Comment: and buddy do not forget if any comment is helpful to you......

Comment: I will not forget your help forever :D
btw i try api 22 of emulator , it works now , i can see data>data>[my package name]>databases
Thanks you truly.